# Cake command DotNetCoreTool fails with "No executable found matching command" on build server

Tags: .net-core, aws-lambda, teamcity, cakebuild

I'm trying to generate a DotNetCore AWS Lambda package on our build server using a Cake Build script:

```
Task("PackageLambda")
.Does(() => 
{
    var projectDirectory = System.IO.Path.Combine(baseDirectory, lambdaProject.BaseDirectory, lambdaProject.ProjectName);
    DotNetCoreTool(
        projectPath: System.IO.Path.Combine(projectDirectory, "SubProject.csproj"),
        command: "lambda", 
        arguments: "package",
    );
});
```

The command fails with `No executable found matching command "dotnet-lambda"` when run under the context of the BuildAgent (running as System)

- Running the build script locally - works
- Running the build script manually on the BuildAgent - works
- Running the build script as the System user ([using `psexec`](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2008/10/22/getting-a-cmd-prompt-as-system-in-windows-vista-and-windows-server-2008/)) on the BuildAgent - works
- Using the [`DoInDirectory`](https://github.com/pitermarx/Cake.DoInDirectory) add-in to set the `WorkingDirectory` - fails

I'm fairly certain the issue is related to the context the CAKE script is called, but can't seem to narrow down what.  We are using this MetaRunner run our CAKE scripts - https://gist.github.com/wwwlicious/620476f5cb8799937db84e24d6b5e75c

Comment: Have you done a .NET restore on the project?

Comment: @devlead running a dotnet restore works locally and from the command line on the Agent.  

When run as a build errors with `error MSB4236: The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' specified could not be found.`

Comment: Also probably worth noting, the script runs fine without needing to run `dotnet restore`.  Which leads me to believe it has more to do with the metarunner than anything else.

Comment: I was able to confirm that `WorkingDirectory` is indeed working as expected and this command is running from the project root.

Comment: I've tried setting `<param name="jetbrains_powershell_bitness" value="x64" />` on the meta runner but still running into the same issue

Answer (score 1):

The underlying issue for this was the environment variable `MSBuildSDKsPath` was being set by a Teamcity configuration value.  The value set was an invalid path.